# How to pick a file from another server on specific schedule by using Asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

I'm working on daily reports project in which data is  imported as .csf format to sql database. Before importing to database, a column of date is added. For this purpose copied to datatable then imported to sql server database. we have to upload daily. I want to make a schedule to import data at specific time from a location (location can be on other server). I am using Asp.net c# Visual studio 2012 Express for Web.
Is there any ASP.net code for this?

Comment: You can use sql server job scheduler to do this.

Comment: I do not export directly to database, before it process  by coping it into a datatable